# Why when checking for video file that was uploaded to youtube processing status the result is all the time null?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, youtube, youtube-api

This is my upload method i'm using to upload video file to youtube.

```
static Video video = null;

        private void UploadVideo(string FileName, string VideoTitle, string VideoDescription)
        {
            try
            {
                UserCredential credential;
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"D:\C-Sharp\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\bin\Debug\client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore("YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;
                }
                var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
                });
                video = new Video();
                video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
                video.Snippet.Title = VideoTitle;
                video.Snippet.Description = VideoDescription;
                video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
                video.Status = new VideoStatus();
                video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public";
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
                {

                    const int KB = 0x400;
                    var minimumChunkSize = 256 * KB;

                    var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video,
                        "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
                    videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged +=
                        videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                    videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived +=
                        videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
                    // The default chunk size is 10MB, here will use 1MB.
                    videosInsertRequest.ChunkSize = minimumChunkSize * 3;
                    dt = DateTime.Now;
                    videosInsertRequest.Upload();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception errors)
            {
                string errorss = errors.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Then in this event i'm creating a Timers timer:

```
    Video objects = null;
    private void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video obj)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += aTimer_Elapsed;
        aTimer.Interval = 10000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        objects = obj;
    }
```

Then in the Elapsed event i'm checking the video file processing status:

```
void aTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            fff = objects.ProcessingDetails.ProcessingStatus;
        }
```

But ProcessingDetails and ProcessingStatus all the time null.
Even if i browse to youtube and see my video file there already online proccessed it's still null in my program.

I want to check in real time every 10 seconds to see if the video is still in process mode and when the process mode finished.

Comment: From your code it is not visible where ProcessingDetails.ProcessingStatus is being set. You show the retrieval attempt but where or how does that object get any value assigned?

Comment: Ok i changed it made the video variable global and in the timer tick event i did: fff = objects.ProcessingDetails.ProcessingStatus = video.ProcessingDetails.ProcessingStatus; but still it's null.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following code

```
 while (true)
 {
       string status = video.Status.UploadStatus;
 }
```

at the end of your UploadVideo() method. How is that supposed to work - an infinite loop? It's never going to end.

Comment: You right i removed it already it was a mistake. Still it's not working with the process status.